# Sitecore 8.2 Custom facets not updating in mongo db

Tags: experience-profile, contact-facets

We are trying to implement custom facets and the implementation is completed. My implementation is based on the below blogs,

https://www.xcentium.com/blog/2017/07/05/adding-a-custom-contact-facet-in-sitecore
https://sukeshtechblog.wordpress.com/custom-xdb-contact-facets/

But currently after implementing, i'm invoking the create custom facet function on my page. My contact is visible in experience profile. I also confirmed by viewing the contact using sitecore API : /sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/CONTACT_ID. But I still see only the default facets. I do not see my custom facets.

For updating custom facets in old contacts, we need to rebuild the analytics index. But Is there any step required to insert the custom facet to update in new contacts?

I also see no exceptions in my logs too.

Comment: Are you waiting until sessions ends before you check in Mongo? 8.2 writes facets on session close.

Comment: yes, I have a custom API which abandons the Session. So I manually call it after invoking my custom facets function. That’s the reason I was able to see my contacts with default facet in exp profile.